# How to only crawl certain URLs from a CSV file with python?

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I have a CSV file with a lot or URLs, all with different domain extensions (`.com`, `.eu`, `.org` and so forth). But I only want to crawl domains with the `.nl` extension using `if '.nl' in row:` in python 2.7:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

fieldnames = ['Website', '@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion']

def csv_writerheader(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()

def csv_writer(dictdata, path):
    with open(path, 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(dictdata)

csv_output_file = 'output!.csv'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')    

keywords = ['@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion']

csv_writerheader(csv_output_file)

with open('top1m-edited.csv') as example_file:
    example_reader = csv.reader(example_file)
    for row in example_reader:

        # INITIALIZE DICT
        data = {'Website': row}

        if '.nl' in row:  # MAKING THE DOMAIN DISTINCTION HERE
            try:
                driver.get(row[0])
                html = driver.page_source    

                for searchstring in keywords:
                    if searchstring.lower() in html.lower():
                        print (row, searchstring, 'FOUND!')
                        data[searchstring] = 'FOUND!'
                    else:
                        print (row, searchstring, 'not found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'not found'    

                csv_writer(data, csv_output_file)

            except:
                pass
```

Printed result:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/Jacob/PycharmProjects/Testing/fooling around 2.py"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my script basically doesn't do anything in this state except for exporting a CSV file with pretty much no results.

However, when i simply leave out `if '.nl' in row:`, the script works perfectly.

What adjustment should I make to only import/scrape `.nl` domain URLs with the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row in example_reader:
```

The row `type` is a list. So it is looking for an item in the list that is exactly ".nl". You have a few options here. If the CSV file will only contain one column with the URL's, you can change this:

```
if '.nl' in row:
```

to this:

```
if '.nl' in row[0]:
```

EDIT: furthermore, any assignment you have for `row` will need to be changed to `row[0]`, such as `data = {'Website': row[0]}`